# How to restore a guest Windows 2012 R2 VM installation/backup from VMWare to OpenStack?

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration, openstack

I have a VMWare VM with Windows 2012 R2 installed in DC#1. The machine has terminal services set up with user accounts and permissions, lots of software installed and bunch of things configured that would probably take me many hours or even days to re-create on a brand new machine.

Due to some issues in DC#1 it was decided to move to a new VM in DC#2. A new VM with fresh Windows 2012 R2 was provided which ended up being based on OpenStack and now I'm trying to find a simplest way to transfer the whole OS with all settings from DC#1 (a VMWare VM) to DC#2 (an OpenStack VM).

The very first thing I attempted was using the built in "Windows Server Backup" tool to create a full backup of VM#1 which I stored on a shared folder and then restored it within the freshly installed Windows 2012 R2 in VM#2. The process completed successfully but the new VM wasn't able to boot anymore which I'm assuming is because of all the VMWare drivers that shouldn't be there in an OpenStack VM (*may be I should've syspreped the system before backing it up somehow? I don't have any physical access to any of the servers though*).

**What are my options to quickly migrate the existing OS into a new VM with a freshly installed same OS keeping all the software, settings, user accounts, folder permissions, etc?**

I guess finding another VMWare VM would be the simplest thing to do but my options are only an OpenStack VM or possibly a bare metal dedicated server.

Would any third party solutions like "Symantec System Recovery Server Edition" be able to help me?

P.S: I do not have ANY access to the host hypervisors and/or the physical servers/locations.

P.S.#2: DC == Data Center != Domain Controller, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it isn't a good practice to have users RDPing into a DC and using applications. I don't know your business need, but it sounds like you have a good opportunity to start fresh and do it the correct way by setting up applications on their own servers.

Comment: @Nixphoe, I know it's been a while but I just saw your response and got curious by your statement - unless you took DC for Domain Controller which would explain you response but I meant Data Center (which probably wasn't clear at all) - **why is it not a good practice to have users RDPing**?